# Django Filters: Suggest improvements to dynamic filtering logic

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-q

I am performing filtration on my dataset based on many kinds of search criterias selected by users on the frontend. Here are a few considerations:

- All the filter criterias are non-mandatory. The user can select/enter values or leave it blank. The backend has to figure out a way to check NULLs.
- Dropdowns are multi-select so the filter form data could have multiple lists of ids. (lots of IN queries)
- There are DATE (from/to) related fields as well which can be left blank. So the code has to handle the following scenarios: Date Range filtration | Date > DDMMYYYY | Date < DDMMYYYY.

Here is how the form looks:
[image: my form]

This is my current approach:

```
class BookingExportFilterBackend(generic_filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        predicate = request.data

        if all(dt in predicate for dt in ('from_date', 'to_date')):
            queryset = queryset.filter(date__range=(predicate['from_date'], predicate['to_date']))

        if 'from_date' in predicate and 'to_date' not in predicate:
            queryset = queryset.filter(date__gte=predicate['from_date'])

        if 'to_date' in predicate and 'from_date' not in predicate:
            queryset = queryset.filter(date__lte=predicate['to_date'])

        if 'state' in predicate:
            queryset = queryset.filter(state__in=predicate['state'])

        if 'clients' in predicate:
            queryset = queryset.filter(client__in=predicate['clients'])

        if 'camera_operators' in predicate:
            queryset = queryset.filter(camera_operator__uuid__in=predicate['camera_operators'])

        return queryset
```

I feel that it can be improved, especially the date part. I am using the `Q` library as well but I'm pretty new to Django. (PS: I've come from Java/Spring/Hibernate background).

Please help improve the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the [django-filters](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#the-filter) lib for filtering. It is quite simple to use and provides a range of filtering options.

For your case, you could start with something like this:
Note: please do not use date as a field/variable name, I have replaced with booking_date in the example below.

```
class BookingFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    from_date = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='booking_date', lookup_expr='gt')
    to_date = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='booking_date', lookup_expr='lt')

    status = django_filters.CharFilter(name="status", lookup_type="contains"

    class Meta:
        model = Booking # replace with your appropriate Model
```